# Abel transform a topological isomorphism?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, representation-theory

Given a noncompact semisimple Lie group $G=NAK$ with Weyl group $W$, consider the symmetric space $X=G/K$. Let $f$ be a function in $D(X)^K$, the space of $K$-invariant functions on $X$. Then the Abel transform
$$a^z\int_N f(an)dn$$
where $z$ is complex, is a topological isomorphism from $D(X)^K$ to $D(A)^W$ as convolution algebras. (Source: this [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=agjtCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=abel%20transform%20convolution%20functions&source=bl&ots=h9xozBpD1l&sig=0GUNt2JmZJ01cKsq9PcciA_1kBQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBWoVChMIyc3lhqvAyAIVxsk-Ch2TwA08#v=onepage&q=abel%20transform%20convolution%20functions&f=false))

Questions:

1. Can someone point me to a reference of a proof of this fact?
2. Is there an analogous isomorphism if one restricts to smooth, compactly supported functions?
3. Specifically, I would like to use $G=SL_2({\bf R})$, which is not semisimple. Does the statement still hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question in [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91937/abel-transform-is-an-isomorphism-for-sl2-r), particularly in the reference Lang's SL(2,R).